# WPF binding subcontrols to a parent control

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to perform databinding, given the following case:

I have a class called "Node" that has two properties: "speed" and "pauseTime". I then have an array of Nodes.

In my XAML, I have a numeric control (labeled Node) that allows the user to switch between Nodes. There are also two subcontrols which I want to have show speed and pauseTime for the selected Node.

My question is how do I set the databinding for speed, for example, so that it shows the speed for the selected Node in the Nodes array based on the value in the Node numeric control?

I tried googling this, but am not sure what search terms to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by numeric control, but I knocked up an example of a master details control scenario.

In the XAML you have a Grid with a ListView (the master), and a TextBlock (the details):

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="masterListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding  ElementName=masterListView, Path=SelectedItem.Speed}" />
    </Grid>
```

The code behind looks like this:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new Node[] 
            {
                new Node() { Speed = 1, PauseTime = "1 Min", Name = "Item 1" },
                new Node() { Speed = 2, PauseTime = "2 Mins" , Name = "Item 2" }
            };
        }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public int Speed { get; set; }

        public string PauseTime { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The child TextBlock binds to the Speed property of the Selected node. If you add IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" to the ListView, the first item will automatically be selected when the window is loaded. If you Google master details/WPF and IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" you will find more details.

It would probably also be useful to Google how to do this using MVVM- a reasonable approach is mentioned in [this Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183176/implementing-a-simple-master-detail-scenario-for-wpf-in-mvvm).

Comment: Sorry, a Numeric Control is basically just a textbox formatted for only numbers. I don't think I can use the approach spelled out above because a ListView has an ItemsSource property. But I am trying to fill the child controls according to an array by taking the array index from the number in the numeric control (textbox). Does that make sense?