# Create WPF UI from JSON schema

Tags: c#, json, wpf, jsonschema

Is there a way to create a WPF UI using a JSON Schema? I am aware that it is possible to convert it into a HTML form with the help of AngularJS and others. But looking for a way to create WPF out of the same has not been fruitful.

There exists a [Source by Rico Suter](https://github.com/RSuter/VisualJsonEditor)
on how to create a Visual Json Editor. My requirement is slightly different from what is given here. In my case, I want to create WPF controls based on the schema and the properties mentioned within the schema. And, with the help of the UI, I want to be able to create as many JSON objects by entering the values into the UI controls.

For example, let's consider the below JSON schema as a sample.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {},
  "id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "properties": {
    "checked": {
      "default": false,
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "id": "/properties/checked",
      "title": "The Checked Schema",
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "dimensions": {
      "id": "/properties/dimensions",
      "properties": {
        "height": {
          "default": 10,
          "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
          "id": "/properties/dimensions/properties/height",
          "title": "The Height Schema",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "width": {
          "default": 5,
          "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
          "id": "/properties/dimensions/properties/width",
          "title": "The Width Schema",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    },
    "id": {
      "default": 1,
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "id": "/properties/id",
      "title": "The Id Schema",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "default": "A green door",
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "id": "/properties/name",
      "title": "The Name Schema",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "price": {
      "default": 12.5,
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "id": "/properties/price",
      "title": "The Price Schema",
      "type": "number"
    },
    "tags": {
      "id": "/properties/tags",
      "items": {
        "default": "home",
        "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
        "id": "/properties/tags/items",
        "title": "The Empty Schema",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

I want to be able to display a checkbox for the `checked` property. Similarly, a `GroupBox` or something with 2 `TextBox` controls within to enter the dimensions(height and width). This UI should enable the user to enter desired values based on which a JSON object can be generated. Something like,

```
{
  "checked": false,
  "dimensions": {
    "width": 5,
    "height": 10
  },
  "id": 1,
  "name": "A green door",
  "price": 12.5,
  "tags": [
    "home",
    "green"
  ]
}
```

Currently, I am creating a list of `JSchema` objects and and deserializing every property into type `JSchema` and then adding it to the list. And thereafter, I am trying to create controls for the same. This is just messy and I have not completely reached my goal. Yet I do not feel that I will be satisfied with the end result. If you could suggest a way to achieve the same it would be of great help. Thanks.

Samples taken from

[here.](https://jsonschema.net/#/editor)

Comment: *"I want to be able to display a checkbox for the checked property"* - cool idea, how far are you with implementing it?

Comment: Why don't you use any library to convert the json data to normal model class that you will use to make your view model. e.g. Newtonsoft.json

Comment: It is certainly *possible* to do this, but there is nothing built in, and it won't be simple to implement.  The basic idea would be to recursively walk through the JSON, and programatically instantiate controls, set properties on them, then add them to whatever the parent item currently is.  It could be done with some creative use of MVVM and data binding too.

Comment: @MaheshMalpani I do not have any json data . All I have is the schema.

Comment: @BradleyUffner At the moment, I am recursively going through the json and creating the controls. It is just that it is making everything including the UI quite messy. Which is why I needed to know if there is anything already existing.

Answer (score 2):

So, it is certainly possible. What you would need to do is define the deserialization routine to make `List<T>/ObservableCollection<T>` objects that implement `INotifyPropeertyChanged`. You could do this via `Newtonsoft Json` or write a `JSchema` to `ViewModel` converter

Next, you can make a `ContentControl` or even a `Listbox/StackPanel` bound to this enumerable, like a Master Detail view, and the details view can implement a `Property Grid` on a selected object. [Example of Property grid](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home).

Make sure all your bindings are `TwoWay` to preserve changes you make.
Additionally, you could implement the `OnSelectionChanged` event on your `StackPanel` to serialize the changes.

### Resources

[Master detail view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183176/implementing-a-simple-master-detail-scenario-for-wpf-in-mvvm)

[Property grid source](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do same thing for UWP, but didn't find a working solution that I could use.
Besides PropertyGrid mentioned above I also found
[DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid#sample-code) from Windows Community Toolkit and [DataForm](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/raddataform/dataform-overview) from Telerik.
Using those still would require converting Json to Object model and back.
As it turned out Newtonsoft.Json is built with databinding in mind, so it is pretty easy to generate controls from Json that would bind to Json properties.
Here is a code snippet to do that:

```
private void RenderForm(JArray jArray)
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
    this.Content = stackPanel;
    stackPanel.Height = this.Height;
    stackPanel.Width = this.Width;
    stackPanel.Children.Add(button);
    foreach (JObject element in jArray)
    {
        String type = element["type"].ToString();
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = element["name"].ToString() };
        textBlock.Padding = new Thickness() { Top = 5 };
        switch (type)
        {
            case "hiddendata":
                break;
            case "bool":
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                checkBox.DataContext = element;
                Binding checkBoxBinding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("[value].Value"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
                checkBoxBinding.Source = element;
                checkBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, checkBoxBinding);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(checkBox);
                break;
            case "image":
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(element["value"].Value<String>()))
                {
                    Image image = new Image();
                    image.MaxHeight = 200;
                    image.MaxWidth = 200;
                    var ignore = SetImageSource(element["value"].Value<String>(), image);
                    stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
                    stackPanel.Children.Add(image);
                }
                break;
            case "info":
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(element["value"].Value<String>()))
                {
                    TextBlock displayTextBlock = new TextBlock();
                    displayTextBlock.DataContext = element;
                    Binding displayTextBlockBinding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("[value].Value"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
                    displayTextBlockBinding.Source = element;
                    displayTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, displayTextBlockBinding);
                    stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
                    stackPanel.Children.Add(displayTextBlock);
                }
                break;
            case "password":
                PasswordBox passwordBox = new PasswordBox();
                passwordBox.DataContext = element;
                Binding passwordBoxBinding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("[value].Value"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
                passwordBoxBinding.Source = element;
                passwordBox.SetBinding(PasswordBox.PasswordProperty, passwordBoxBinding);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(passwordBox);
                break;
            case "string":
            default:
                TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                textBox.DataContext = element;
                Binding textBoxBinding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("[value].Value"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
                textBoxBinding.Source = element;
                textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textBoxBinding);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```